# How to Enable and disable a button if textbox is empty or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable or disable a button on the basis of the textbox being empty, actually, if user is logged in then the Email is comping from logged in user

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("Email").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = false;
    }


    if (document.getElementById("PhoneNoTextbox").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("PhoneBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("PhoneBtn").disabled = false;
    }
});
```

```
<label class="form-label QstFonts mx-4 my-4">Please Enter Your Email Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                        <span class="QstFontssmall">Please make sure that your Email is correct.</span>
                                                        <div class="px-0">
                                                            <div class="pt-4 mx-5 d-flex row">
                                                                <div class="row m-auto form-icon">
                                                                    <i data-feather="mail" class="fa fa-envelope icons"></i>
                                                                                                                                            <input id="Email"
                                                                           type="email"
                                                                           asp-for="HLApplication.UserEmail"
                                                                           autocomplete="off"
                                                                           class="input-text form-control-input m-auto p-3"
                                                                           placeholder="Email"
                                                                           required="" />
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="row m-auto my-3">
                                                                    <button id="Continuebtn"
                                                                            type="button"
                                                    class="btn btn-primary m-auto p-3">
                                                                        NEXT
                                                                    </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the content is coming from a Server-Side Script, PHP or ASP, I suspect this is what is populating the `Email` and `Phone` text boxes. If this is the case, it might be better to have that script enable or disable the buttons. JavaScript/jQuery is Client-Side Scripting. It is run when the document loads in the browser, not before. Your script will only execute code when it is loaded. If you want the buttons to appear when they user enters text, you need to bind this code to an event, like `change`. You may also want to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created the validation function for email. Please try to do like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("Email").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = false;
    }
});
const validateEmail = (email) => {
  return email.match(
    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
  );
};

const validate = () => {
  const email = $('#Email').val();

  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = true;
  }
  return false;
}

$('#Email').on('input', validate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function disableButton(sel, bool) {
    $(sel).prop("disabled", bool);
  }
  if ($("#Email").val() == "") {
    disableButton("#Continuebtn", true);
  }
  $("#Email").keyup(function() {
    var v = $(this).val();
    if (v === "") {
      // Empty
      disableButton("#Continuebtn", true);
    } else {
      // Populated
      if ((v.indexOf("@") !== -1) && (v.indexOf(".") !== -1)) {
        // Possible Email format
        disableButton("#Continuebtn", false);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="form-label QstFonts mx-4 my-4">Please Enter Your Email Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<span class="QstFontssmall">Please make sure that your Email is correct.</span>
<div class="px-0">
  <div class="pt-4 mx-5 d-flex row">
    <div class="row m-auto form-icon">
      <i data-feather="mail" class="fa fa-envelope icons"></i>
      <input id="Email" type="email" asp-for="HLApplication.UserEmail" autocomplete="off" class="input-text form-control-input m-auto p-3" placeholder="Email" required="" />
    </div>
    <div class="row m-auto my-3">
      <button id="Continuebtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-auto p-3">NEXT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the page loads, it checks for a `value` in the textbox. If it is empty, the button is disabled.

When the User enters some value, it is checked again. If it is Empty, the button is disabled. If it has content, it checks to see if it is an Email like format. This is a very basic check for the `@` symbol and a `.` symbol. If these are present, then the button is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var email = document.getElementById("Email");
email.addEventListener('keyup', () =>{
    if (email.value === "") {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Continuebtn").disabled = false;
    }

/*
    if (document.getElementById("PhoneNoTextbox").value === "") {
        document.getElementById("PhoneBtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("PhoneBtn").disabled = false;
    }
*/
})
```

```html
<label class="form-label QstFonts mx-4 my-4">Please Enter Your Email Address <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<span class="QstFontssmall">Please make sure that your Email is correct.</span>
<div class="px-0">
  <div class="pt-4 mx-5 d-flex row">
     <div class="row m-auto form-icon">
       <i data-feather="mail" class="fa fa-envelope icons"></i>
          <input id="Email" type="email" asp-for="HLApplication.UserEmail" autocomplete="off" class="input-text form-control-input m-auto p-3" placeholder="Email" 
                                                                           required="" />
    </div>
    <div class="row m-auto my-3">
       <button id="Continuebtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-auto p-3" disabled>
                                                                        NEXT
                                                                    </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```